# Encode строки обратно в JSON на русском, C#

Tags: c#, json, json-encode

Мне надо забрать Json файл, и поменять какое то значение, и снова вернуть его в Json файл, но т.к. в файле используется русский язык он закодирован в формате /uXXXX, но после Deserialize\Serialize он возвращает значение на русском языке без кодировки, команда JsonEncodedText частично решает проблему, но он частично решает проблему но он так же кодирует кавычки.

```
questAsuEDO? jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestAsuEDO>(json);

//data": {
//      "Name": "\u0423\u0447 }
jsonObj.data.Name = "Пример";

string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.None);
//data": {
//      "Name": "Пример" }
        
var outputEncode = Convert.ToString(JsonEncodedText.Encode(output));
//data\0022: {
//      "Name\0022: \0022\u043F\u0440\u0438\u043C\u0435\u0440 }
```

Comment: `jsonObj.data.Name = JsonEncodedText.Encode("Пример");`

Comment: Но зачем? Любой парсер должен уметь читать utf-8.

Comment: Я поддерживаю AlexeyTen. Эти трансформации не нужны.

Comment: Вы используете Newtonsoft.Json, но вместе с тем `JsonEncodedText` - это тип из System.Text.Json. Не смешивайте два разных API! PS: кстати, System.Text.Json по умолчанию при сериализации даст желаемый результат. Используйте его, откажитесь от Newtonsoft.

Comment: `string output = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonObj)`

Comment: Да действительно помогло, System.Text.Json

Comment: Чтобы не было конфликтов, лучше удалите NuGet пакет Newtonsoft.Json из проекта.